# mysql query to select everything except

Tags: sql, mysql

i have two mysql tables.

the first is called "chosen" and consists of id, user_id, and widget_id fields.

the other is called "widgets" and includes several things including widget_id.

i created a filter so that the user can either display widgets that he/she has chosen, or widgets that he/she hasn't chosen. for the ones he has chosen, i use this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM widgets, chosen 
 WHERE chosen.user_id = $user_id 
   AND chosen.widget_id = widgets.widget_id
```

however, i can't figure out how to display the ones that he/she hasn't chosen. this doesn't work (displays everything):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM widgets, chosen 
 WHERE !(    chosen.user_id = $user_id 
         AND chosen.widget_id = widgets.widget_id)
```

how do i do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Using NOT IN:

```
SELECT w.*
  FROM WIDGET w
 WHERE w.widget_id NOT IN (SELECT c.widget
                             FROM CHOSEN c
                            WHERE c.user_id = $user_id)
```

### Using NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT w.*
  FROM WIDGET w
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM CHOSEN c
                    WHERE c.widget_id = w.widget_id 
                      AND c.user_id = $user_id)
```

### LEFT JOIN/IS NULL:

```
   SELECT w.*
     FROM WIDGET w
LEFT JOIN CHOSEN c ON c.widget_id = w.widget
                  AND c.user_id = $user_id
    WHERE w.widget IS NULL
```

### Performance:

If the [columns compared (widget_id in either table) are not nullable, LEFT JOIN/IS NULL performs the best on MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).  If the [columns are nullable (the value could be NULL), NOT IN or NOT EXISTS perform better](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/).

Comment: thanks! i ended up using "SELECT * from widgets w WHERE w.widget_id NOT IN (SELECT w.widget_id FROM widgets w, chosen c WHERE c.widget_id = w.widget_id AND c.user_id = $user_id)"

Answer (score 1):

Boolean logic: `(ab)'` is the same as `a' + b'`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM widgets, chosen 
 WHERE chosen.user_id <> $user_id 
         OR chosen.widget_id <> widgets.widget_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to select all rows from `widgets` that have no associated row in `chosen` for the given `$user_id`. You can accomplish this with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` looking for the rows that didn't match in the `chosen` table. Something like this:

```
SELECT w.* FROM widgets as w
LEFT OUTER JOIN chosen as c on c.widget_id=w.widget_id AND c.user_id=$user_id
WHERE c.id IS NULL;
```

BTW: I recommend using the newer join syntax over the comma delimited tables join syntax. It's easier to read and understand, especially when it comes to outer joins.