# Simple MySQL query, ON JOINS

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have two tables, `Car` table and `Driver` table.

In Driver table there are `name`, `birthDate`, and `id`.
In Car table there are `regNo`, `manuID`, `colour`, `price`, and `driverID`.

THE `driverID` and `id` **match**, but there is one `Driver.id` which is not in `Car.driverID`

How will I be able to display only the one which is not in Car table.

I tried this:

```
SELECT id FROM Driver JOIN Car ON Car.driverID!=Driver.id;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery.

```
SELECT id FROM Driver WHERE id not in (select distinct driverid from car)
```

Comment: It is efficient to use 'left join' than this 'not in'.

Comment: @rs2012 Yes it is, and I'm surprised the answers showing that have not been upvoted more.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this

```
SELECT * FROM `driver` WHERE `id` not in(select `driverId` from `car`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Cars AS C
LEFT JOIN Drivers AS D ON d.id=c.driverId
WHERE d.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Your ans will give me cars which have no drivers... not drivers with no cars. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use join, then you can do :

```
SELECT d.id
FROM Driver d
LEFT JOIN Car c ON (d.id=c.driverID)
WHERE c.driverID is NULL;
```

You can also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405729/mysql-query-to-select-everything-except) for other ways to do this.