# Set difference operator in MySQL

Tags: mysql, set-difference

The following questions pertain to a database with the following tables.

```
Suppliers - S (S#, Name, Status, City)
Parts - P (P#, Pname, Colour, Weight, City)
Projects - J (J#, Jname, City)
Shipment - SPJ (S#, P#, J#, Qty)
```

The significance of an SPJ record is that the specified supplier supplies the specified part to the specified project in the specified quantity (and the combination S#-P#-J# uniquely identifies such a record).

I have to get the following:
All S#, P#, J# triples such that they are not all co-located.

I have tried the following query but it gives a syntax error.

```
(select s#,j#,p# from s cross join p cross join j)
except
(select s#,j#,p# from s natural join p natural join j)
```

Am I getting it correct?  If not, then correct me. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently MySQL does not have `EXCEPT` ([www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-except-clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-except-clause.htm)), so you will have to use something like the suggestions in [mysql query to select everything except](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405729/mysql-query-to-select-everything-except).