# Alternative for except in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a DB table `company` that has the columns `company-name` and `city`.  I want to execute a query in mysql that finds all companies
located in every city in which 'Small Bank Corporation' is located.  A company may be located in several cities.

One solution can be:

```
select c1.company-name
    from company c1
    where not exists
    ((select city from company
          where company.company-name = 'Small Bank Corporation')
      except (select city from company c2
              where c1.company-name = c2.company-name))
```

But 'except' doesn't work in mysql. So what is the possible solution in mysql?

Comment: Using `company-name` as a column name is annoying since it'll have to be escaped constantly.

Comment: Is that an exercice asked at school ?

Comment: You looking for `not in` clause

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405729/mysql-query-to-select-everything-except

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you made this so complicated:

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_name
  FROM company
  WHERE city IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT city FROM company WHERE company_name='Small Bank Corporation'
  ) AND company_name!='Small Bank Corporation'
```

This is a more literal translation of what you expressed in English.

It's worth noting this data does not seem properly normalized.

Comment: Why is there a DISTINCT in the subquery

Comment: so every company name will be displayed only once

Comment: to reduce the number of output results. It does not matter in this case though.

Comment: @SashiKant Maybe there's more than one in each city. It keeps the amount of cities to match to a minimum.

Comment: I would rather have `SELECT DISTINCT company_name... `

Comment: one more thing, your query will result only Small Bank Corporation

Comment: I think only `select c1.company-name
    from company c1
    where 
    company-name != 'Small Bank Corporation'
  `
will get the results what OP is asking, but I think he himself confused

Comment: @SashiKant That just gets all companies not named that, not all those in the same cities.

Comment: this will return the company_names for companies which are located in 'at least one' city where 'Small Bank Corp.' is located while the question says the companies should be located in 'every' city as 'Small Bank Corp.'

Answer (score 0):

The subquery finds all cities the Small Bank Corporation is in and then the main query finds all companies located in those cities.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.company-name 
FROM company s
WHERE city ALL (SELECT DISTINCT t.city FROM company t WHERE t.company-name = 'Small Bank Corporation')
AND t.company-name != s.company-name
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are sometimes good enough, but code+explanation answers are always better

Comment: this will return the company_names for companies which are located in 'at least one' city where 'Small Bank Corp.' is located while the question says the companies should be located in 'every' city as 'Small Bank Corp.'

Comment: still not working.. a single city cannot be compared to two or more cities for equality..ALL will work for '>' '<' comparison operators, not with '='.